# How to convert an IF statement to a function?

Tags: php, function, if-statement

Synopsis:
 At the top of the page, I've set up a bunch of things to include, headers,body,footer, and some variables unique to the page in question.. (such as if the page is the contact page or if it's the homepage)

At the top of this page, is an IF statement, basically asking if we need to get mySQL database credentials or not.

I'd like to turn this IF statement into a function.

The IF statement: (I still haven't tested to see if it'll work or not)

```
$yesDBconnect = REQUIRE_ONCE ('{GURL}/include/mysql_con.php');

$DBconnect = FALSE;
$yesDBconnect = REQUIRE_ONCE ('{GURL}/include/mysql_con.php');
    if ($DBconnect == TRUE)
        $yesDBconnect
    endif;
```

I'd like it to be a function like, connect_to(YES); or connect_to(NO);
I'm pretty new to this, I've got my variables down, but other then that I'm slacking. :P

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem with doing it in a function is that any variables your included files create, such as a "global" database handle variable, will be stuck inside that function's scope. When it returns, they go poof.

Comment: not if you use static class methods and class vars.

Comment: Could you elaborate? In my mysql_con file I have constants with user,password,host,database inside. If I try to use a function, those constants will disappear?

Answer (score 0):

You ought to use `require_once` (lowercase), which is a language construct and doesn't need its argument in parenthesis.

When using alternate control structures, you should place a colon (`:`) at the end of your condition.

If using what you suggest, make sure the `mysql_con.php` file uses...

```
return array(
   'host' => 'localhost',
   ...
);
```

...or similar.

Comment: `$yesDBconnect = REQUIRE_ONCE '{GURL}/include/mysql_con.php';

$DBconnect = FALSE;
$yesDBconnect = REQUIRE_ONCE '{GURL}/include/mysql_con.php';
    if ($DBconnect == TRUE)
        $yesDBconnect:`
Then change `define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); ...` to `return array(
   'host' => 'localhost',
   ...
);` and of course use a function.. Which I'm still unsure on how to do..